# Emberjs - Using bubbles=false for a {{view Ember.TextField}} doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js, action, handlebars.js

I want this view to have bubbles=false but bubbles does not seem to work with views.

```
{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding=categoryName action="turnOffEditMode" }}
```

to

```
{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding=categoryName action="turnOffEditMode" bubbles=false}}
```

Has anyone had something similar to what I've tried work?

If bubbles can only be used in a handlebar that declares {{action}} at the beginning, is their any way around this?

Comment: is this http://emberjs.jsbin.com/fatomavo/1/edit what you describe? The example contains an `Ember.Textfield` `view` that fires an action when enter is pressed, handled by controller and route but it is configured not to bubble by not returning `true`, as described in http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.TextField.html#toc_bubbling

Comment: `bubbles` applies to an event (action), not a view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be accomplished by including a span class and the action as below

```html
<span {{action "mailToAction" emailer.email bubbles=false}} {{view Ember.ContentProfileEditableView valueBinding="emailer.email" class="contentEditable mail-to-span bnd-cursor" editableBinding="editProfile"}} </span>
```